# missing ; before statement error on google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, percentile

I try my first steps in google script and I try to calculate the percentile of a given range of numbers in a row. I always got a

Missing ; before statement. (line 107, file "Sitan_Code")  error

I don't see the point, why I get this.

could anybody help?

Thanks in advance

```js
function percentile() {
  var tenPercent = 10 / 100; //simsSheet.getRange("I5").getValue() / 100;
  var twentyfivePercent = 25 / 100; //simsSheet.getRange("I6").getValue() / 100;
  var fiftyPercent = 50 / 100; //simsSheet.getRange("I7").getValue() / 100;
  var seventyfivePercent = 75 / 100; //simsSheet.getRange("I8").getValue()/ 100;
  var neintyPercent = 90 / 100; // simsSheet("I9").getValue() / 100;
  var values = simsSheet.getRange("A1:NTP1").getValues().sort();
  var percentage = [tenPercent, twentyfivePercent, fiftyPercent, seventyfivePercent, neintyPercent];

  for (i = 0; i < percentage.length; i++) {
    var index = values.length * percentage[i];

    if ((index % 2) === 0) {

      var average = (index[i] + index[i + 1]) / 2;

      if (percentage[i] == percentage[tenPercent]) {
        var ten = simsSheet.getRange("K5") set.Value(average);
      } else if (percentage[i] == percentage[twentyfivePercent]) {
        var twentyfive = simsSheet.getRange("K6").setValue(average);
      } else if (percentage[i] == percentage[fiftyPercent]) {
        var fivty = simsSheet.getRange("K7").setValue(average);
      } else if (percentage[i] == percentage[seventyfivePercent]) {
        var seventyfive = simsSheet.getRange("K8").setValue(average);
      } else if (percentage[i] == percentage[neintyPercent] {
          var neinty = simsSheet.getRange("K9").setValue(average);
          else {
            inx = Math.round(index);
          }
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: How about adding the script?

Comment: Hmm, how about including the relevant code/ complete code. But there should really be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be missing a few braces and periods that causes the compilation to fail, refer to the version below:

```
function percentile() {
    var tenPercent = 10 / 100; //simsSheet.getRange("I5").getValue() / 100;
    var twentyfivePercent = 25 / 100; //simsSheet.getRange("I6").getValue() / 100;
    var fiftyPercent = 50 / 100; //simsSheet.getRange("I7").getValue() / 100;
    var seventyfivePercent = 75 / 100; //simsSheet.getRange("I8").getValue()/ 100;
    var neintyPercent = 90 / 100; // simsSheet("I9").getValue() / 100;
    var values = simsSheet.getRange("A1:NTP1").getValues().sort();
    var percentage = [tenPercent, twentyfivePercent, fiftyPercent, seventyfivePercent, neintyPercent];

    for (i = 0; i < percentage.length; i++) {
        var index = values.length * percentage[i];

        if ((index % 2) === 0) {

            var average = (index[i] + index[i + 1]) / 2;

            if (percentage[i] == percentage[tenPercent]) {
                var ten = simsSheet.getRange("K5").setValue(average);
            } else if (percentage[i] == percentage[twentyfivePercent]) {
                var twentyfive = simsSheet.getRange("K6").setValue(average);
            } else if (percentage[i] == percentage[fiftyPercent]) {
                var fivty = simsSheet.getRange("K7").setValue(average);
            } else if (percentage[i] == percentage[seventyfivePercent]) {
                var seventyfive = simsSheet.getRange("K8").setValue(average);
            } else if (percentage[i] == percentage[neintyPercent]) {
                var neinty = simsSheet.getRange("K9").setValue(average);
            } else {
                inx = Math.round(index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```